# How to use Linkerd Dynamic Request Routing to point to a Kubernetes Service with the same name/namespace

Tags: kubernetes, linkerd

I need to use Linkerd's dynamic request routing to allow for a quick traffic switch, i.e., like a canary or green/blue deployment.

My Kubernetes services, namespaces are fixed, and Linkerd seems to solve this problem by routing traffic to services, but with different names like `service-1` and `service-2`.

Istio solves this problem pretty well: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/traffic-shifting/

How do I use Linkerd to switch traffic between deployments, not services? Any ideas?